# random.randrange integers to input

Tags: python

I've been trying to add a `input()` function for my code. It is supposed to transfer the `input()` data to the `random.randrange` integers but i can't figure out how to make it work. This is the code i have so far for it.

```
import random
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

print('Welcome!')
time.sleep(0.2)
sec  = input('Till how many seconds do you want to randomize the time? ')



while True:
    keyboard = Controller()

    sleep_time = random.randrange(int(sec))
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    for char in "nnnn":
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.21)
```

Comment: _i can't figure out how to make it work_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AMC with that i meant that the random.randrange function wouldn't work for me, so i was trying to find a solution for an alternative method, which was the random.randint function. Which Holden showcased in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use the `randint` function here

```
sleep_time = random.randint(0, int(sec))
```